# Override SharePoint div class Style with CSS

Tags: css

I have this div:

[image]

I need to make it this:

[image]

I try to do it with `txt` file, that I load in CEWP, `txt` file looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-zone ms-fullWidth
{
     width: 700px;
}
</style>
```

But it does not work. How to do it right?

Comment: Strange but none of the four methods worked in my case oO. Maybe because of CEWP.. I'll try now in Designer

Comment: At the end I modified parent table style, right click in Firebug-> Copy CSS path, and my result CSS became: html body.ms-backgroundImage form#aspnetForm div#s4-workspace.ms-core-overlay div#s4-bodyContainer div#contentRow div#contentBox div#DeltaPlaceHolderMain div.welcome.welcome-links table
{
        width:70%;            !important
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the css as:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.ms-webpart-zone.ms-fullWidth {
        width: 700px;
    }
</style>
```

Note: This change will apply to all your webpart zone(s) in the page. To apply it to a particular element prepend the CSS with a unique element identifier.

Comment: Yes thanks! It works, for both webpartzones in table, so they move both relative to each other :-D So my 'adventures' continue)

Answer (score 1):

Your css is not correct, you are looking for an element with the class `ms-webpart-zone`that has a child element with the class `ms-fullWidth` which is not the case in the markup you show.

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-zone.ms-fullWidth
{
     width: 700px;
}
</style>
```

Or, to be compliant with all browsers (some do not like to combine two classes like I do above):

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-fullWidth
{
     width: 700px;
}
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-webpart-zone
{
     width: 700px;
}
</style>
```

You will have to check yourself which one of the two latest variants that works the best on your specific page.

Comment: By "_compliant with all browsers_" are you referring to <= IE6?

Comment: I just know I have hade troubles with this in some browser / OS combination, might have been IE8 on windows 7 or similar :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JavaScript, you can try using this jQuery in your CEWP. It will inject CSS as an inline style for the specified element:

```
<script src="/link-to-your-jquery-file/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('div.ms-webpart-zone.ms-fullWidth').css('width', '700px');

    });

 </script>
```

Comment: Why would you use jquery to do something that can easily be done with pure css?

Comment: I proposed it because the question asked for a solution that would provide an inline style for the element, which this jQuery does.